# Should the 'nobody' user on my headless Ubuntu server have shell access?

Tags: linux, security, bash, users

I've read conflicting stuff on a few forums etc. regarding this.  When I enter the following line:

```
grep nobody /etc/passwd
```

I get the following output

```
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
```

Should nobody have shell access?  Can you qualify your answers please.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nobody user shouldn't **need** a shell but you could find that changing it may break something on Ubuntu. You can always give it a shot by changing it to nologin and see if anything breaks. There may be other system users that should not have a shell as well, see [Your Distro is Insecure: Ubuntu](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7297/2/). The main reason that nobody shouldn't have a shell is that a lot of externally facing programs like httpd run as nobody and it provides a foothold into your system if someone can compromise the account. Having it set to nologin puts up another hurdle to jump although it probably isn't much of a hurdle.